# How can I load this "label" using importxml & xPath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to get this to load into google spreadsheet, but no success so far:

http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/basic-information?symbol=00027

The, I have the formula as follows:

`=importxml ("http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/basic-information?symbol=" & To_Text(A7),"//td[@id='sb2-last']/label[@id='SQ_Last']/following-sibling::label/text()")`

Result:
The content imported is empty.

The html part:

```
<table> 
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>現價<label id="SQ_Currency">(港元)</label></td> 
            <td id="sb2-last">
                <label id="SQ_Last" class="cls">**57.500**</label>
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/basic-information?symbol="&
 TO_TEXT(A7), "//td[@class='mcFont cls']"), 26)
```

[image]

Comment: Right on! Would that be toto much to ask why this one is not working, though: http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/quick-quote.aspx?symbol=00027    and I have tried the following formula: SEERRO(ÍNDICE(IMPORTXML("http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/quick-quote.aspx?symbol="&TO_TEXT(A6), "//td[@class='txt_r cls font-num']"), 1),"") Thanks a million!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: It's supposed to be the Chg value. Right now, 0.000, as described on the spreadsheet. Thanks a lot

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lRNvAtmxA9XL1Pn8rrJmojg_LeocaHn_jzHmGeWxU1o/edit#gid=815726230